# Как предотвратить генерацию рандомных чисел?

Tags: javascript, dom

В рамках изучения JS решил создать 3 div`а и сделать так, чтобы при наведении на них background-color рандомно менял цвет. Реализовал все таким способом:

```
(function getColor() {
  const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "magenta", "pink"];

  function getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) {
    min = Math.ceil(0);
    max = Math.floor(6);
    let output = Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min; 
    return output;
  }

  function randomColor(someRndNumber, colorArray) {
    let colorResult = colorArray[someRndNumber];
    return colorResult;
  }
  let rndResult = getRandomIntInclusive();
  let rndColor = randomColor(rndResult, colors);

  const getColoredDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".coloredDiv");
  getColoredDivs.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
      elem.style.backgroundColor = rndColor;
      getColor();
    });
  });

  getColoredDivs.forEach((elem) => {
    elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
      elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
    });
  });
})();
```

И первые 10-12 итераций все работает, как я хочу. Цвета на бэках рандомно меняются при наведении курсора на див (представлены на экране, как три квадрата с черными границами), но затем начинается какая-то бесконечная лютая рандомизация цифр(я проверил добавив console.log в функции рандомизаторе). Браузер подвисает. Убить процесс можно только через диспетчер задач. Думаю, что проблема в том, что рандомизация значения от 0 до 6 происходит каждый раз, пока я вожу курсором по поверхности дива. Но, как предотвратить это я пока не знаю)

Comment: А зачем ты вызываешь getColor в mouseover?

Comment: У вас рекурсия и переполнение стека возникает при событии `mouseover`., так как идёт вызов getColor и листенеры снова вешаются и копятся

Comment: я понял. но, если не вызывать при mouseover функцию заново, то выбирается один раз один цвет, отображается на всех квадратах и все. на этом работа кода прекращается. другой цвет будет только после обновления страницы. а я хотел бы сделать так, чтобы каждый раз новый цвет. но, в результате рекурсия и переполнение стека

Comment: Потому что rndColor надо считать внутри обработчика события

Comment: то есть, внутри обработчика события создать функцию, которая будет считать и рандомные цифры и вычислять цвет?

Comment: внутри обработчика *вызывать* функцию

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переусложнил реализацию.. `getRandomIntInclusive(min, max) { min = Math.ceil(0); max = Math.floor(6);` `Math.ceil` округляет до ближайшего большего целого. Смысл операции с `0`.. `Math.floor` округляет до ближайшего меньшего целого. Смысл округлять `6`..

```js
const colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "magenta", "pink"];

const getColoredDivs = document.querySelectorAll(".coloredDiv");

getColoredDivs.forEach((elem) => {

  elem.addEventListener("mouseover", () => {
    //elem.style.backgroundColor = "#"+Math.floor(Math.random()*16777215).toString(16);
    elem.style.backgroundColor = colors[Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length)]
  });

  elem.addEventListener("mouseout", () => {
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "white";
  });

});
```

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.coloredDiv {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
<div class='coloredDiv'></div>
```

Comment: Все работает! И намного проще. Надо запомнить) Спасибо! А рандомизатор я взял с MDN. Передрал под чистую)) А выясняется, что можно было сделать по другому)

Comment: @Pacemaker На здоровье! :) Не запомнить, а разобрать и осмыслить.

Comment: @Pacemaker если ответ Вам помог, то ставьте галочку рядом с ответом как "принятый" чтобы другие могли его найти.

Comment: Всё - галочку поставил! Еще раз - спасибо!

Comment: @Pacemaker Я никогда не прошу. Разобрался?

Comment: Да! Разобрался) попрактиковался и все встало на свои места)